# Websocket onerror callback not does not fire vanillajs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

My websocket onerror callback does not fire when I disconnect the browser which is on a seperate computer from the websocket server on another computer by turning off the wifi connection and sending a message. The message just doesn't send but no error is fired.
Here is my code snippet below.

```js
const logged_in_user_id = 2;

WEBSOCKET_URL = `wss://${window.location.host}/ws/${logged_in_user_id}/`;

const realTimeDataSocket = new WebSocket(WEBSOCKET_URL)

realTimeDataSocket.addEventListener("open", function() {
    console.log("Websocket is opened.");
    realTimeDataSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
        "event": "online",
        "message": "This user is online"
    }))
});

realTimeDataSocket.addEventListener("close", function() {
    console.log("Websocket was closed.");
});

realTimeDataSocket.addEventListener("error", function() {
    console.log("Websocket was closed due to an error.");
});
```

Comment: Snippet is incomplete and therefore not runnable.  Also your description of the actions and outcome is confusing and not very helpful.

Comment: Can you explain what part of the websocket API documentation makes you think that you should be seeing an error event happening in the use-case you describe?

Comment: Okay I found a reason for the behaviour, I noticed this behaviour indicated in this question on  chrome, but firefox/safari does fire the onerror callback. So its browser dependent.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.